# HTML Drawing an image on button click

Tags: javascript, html, image, button

I am new to HTML and tried to figure out how to do this, but I cannot seem to get this to work. I'm trying to make it so that when you hit the button, an image pops up at a defined location.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me!</button>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
    <img id="circle" src="http://imgur.com/2a8Hq06" alt="Circle">
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

(Also the Image isn't loading either)
Thanks!

Comment: The image isn't loading because you're giving it a link to a webpage not an image.